# SSH server for testing

Tags: java, testing, ssh, jsch

I am writing a Java Code to connect to SSH server using JSch.

I have written the code, now have to test it. but i am not allowed to test in the production server.

so is their any SSH server available so I can connect to it to check my code.
I don't want to create any accounts in any websites for SSH account. plz suggest me any SSH server readily available which can be tested with user-name, password, port etc.

Comment: Run a sshd service on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Virtualize

I would recommend setting up [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) as a development/test virtual machine.  This will provide a consistent test environment and you could try to mirror production as closely as possible with various provisioning recipes.

Vagrant will instrument virtualbox and you can choose the base image (ubuntu, centos, etc).  Any of the linux VMs will provide an SSH server.

From vagrantup.com once vagrant (and virtualbox are installed):

```
vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box
vagrant init lucid32
vagrant up
```

At that point you will have an ssh server running at localhost:2222

This command will get you into the box:

```
vagrant ssh
```

And from there you can add accounts and test.  Any files from the host machine's current directory will be mounted at /vagrant/ (your source files, etc).

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to have an actual server to log into.  YOu need an ssh account with username, password/keys etc.  You can do it on your own computer (localhost).  I doubt you'll get the true SSH experience with any SSH simulators available online (which is what im guessing your after...).  If you're just asking someone if they have some random server taht you can practice your SSH skills on, then you probably won't find that either.

If you don't want to ssh into your own computer and don't have another box to test on, you can create virtualized servers for cheap using AWS EC2 or the rackspace cloud or pretty much any cloud computing provider to name a few...